# Is it a WCAG 2.0 AA violation if the label of a checkbox is a hyperlink?

Tags: html, checkbox, hyperlink, accessibility, wcag2.0

I have 4 check boxes and labels corresponding to each is a hyperlink which takes user to the start page of that particular topic. So basically selecting the checkbox has a different function while activating the link performs another function.I know it is not a recommended practice, but can I mark it against any WCAG criteria?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, 'yes', it violates WCAG [3.2.2 On Input](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#on-input), which is a A (single-A) requirement.

It's not really a great UX for anyone.  When you programmatically associate a label with a checkbox using the `for` attribute such as:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<label for="foo">history</label>
```

this allows mouse users to click on either the box itself or on the label.  If you make the label a link, then clicking on the label will navigate to the links destination instead of checking the box.  This would violate the Understandable principle of WCAG, in particular, [3.2.2 On Input](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#on-input)

From a screen reader perspective, the issue isn't as bad.  For the following code:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<label for="foo">
  <a href="some url">history</a>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="bar">
<label for="bar">favorites</label>
```

as I <kbd>tab</kbd> through the interface, I will hear "history checkbox, not checked" and "favorites checkbox, not checked".  Those sound normal.  However, in between those two I will hear "history link".  The history link will seem to be just "floating out there" in between two checkboxes.  The checkboxes will behave correctly and the link will behave correctly, but only because a screen reader user that is not using any vision will not attempt to select the link as the checkbox label.

If you have a low vision user that augments their sight by using a screen reader, they may see some semblance of a checkbox and a label and try to click the label with the mouse and will be confused if taken to a link destination.